# Striking a vertical line to make user understand that two li elements forming a group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my HTML page which containg several LI elements and I want to add a grouping feature on my LI elements.For example for the elements 'college' and 'automobile' I want to apply grouping and I have applied same groupid on them and applied margin to distinguish them. But I want to apply a vertical line so that user can properly understand that those two LI elements are grouped.Like this one.

[image: Group Pic]

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li title="Insurance">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>Malpractice</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li title="Construction">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>Carpentry</span>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li title="Education" id="grp1" style="margin-left:20px;">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>College</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li title="Insurance" id="grp1" style="margin-left:20px;">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>Automobile</span>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li title="Education">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>Iron Worker</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li title="Insurance">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <span>High School</span>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs should be usique. Use a class or a data attribute instead: `data-id`.

Comment: ok I will modify that but what about the actual problem

Comment: You can use `:first-child` and `:last-child` and set `border-top` on the first and `border-bottom` on the second.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
$(document).on("click", "ul", function() {
  alert("Clicked!");
})
```

```css
.grouped {
  border-left: solid 15px pink;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grouped:before {
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  content: "\f03a";
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.grouped li {
  list-style: none;
}

.grouped li span {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="grouped">
  <li><input type="text"><span>College</span></li>
  <li><input type="text"><span>Automobile</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes it is quite ok but in that icon I want a click even so that when I will click on that I can fire a javascript for ungrouping

Comment: I have adjusted the code. You can now click on the icon.

Comment: You have applied grouping on all LI elements I want to apply it only on the LI elements which have the id grp1

Comment: I also want a click event on that font awesome icon

Comment: IDs must be unique, so that won't work. And like I said 15 minutes ago, you can click on the icon.

Comment: How can i click on that icon

Answer (score 0):

You have to change that id attribute for class attribute, since you are working with stylesheet here and id is unique, can't use it multiple times like you are using.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li title="Insurance">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" >
                <span>Malpractice</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li title="Construction">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" >
                <span>Carpentry</span>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li title="Education" class="grp1" style="margin-left:20px;">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" >
                <span>College</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li title="Insurance" class="grp1" style="margin-left:20px;">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" >
                <span>Automobile</span>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li title="Education">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" >
                <span>Iron Worker</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li title="Insurance">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" >
                <span>High School</span>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can do the following

```
li.grp1 {
    border-left: 3px solid blue;
}
```

PS. remember to not close input tags, inputs were designed to be an element, not a container so there is no open and close tag here.

Comment: It is striking line but I need line with an button for ungrouping it